# Flutter rive_core cached package gives error: The class 'DependencySorter' is abstract and can't be instantiated

Tags: ios, flutter

I have come across the error in the question title. What I expect to happen is that a iOS build is made and for the code to then run on a device connected to my macBook. `flutter doctor` gives no errors.

Instead of completing, I keep having this error:

[image: My iOS build rive error]

Things I have tried are: (Not in order of trying)

```
flutter clean
deleting pod files and running pod install
flutter pub cache clean
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I needed to update the rive version to latest (in our case 0.11.2, from 0.10.4) this was also done on projects that this one depends on.

Comment: Thanks so much for this<3This saved me from making some very BAD decisions